# Class Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler is not autoloadable, can not call symfony-scripts script

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

We have the below contents on `composer.json` with dependencies and scripts. This comes from a legacy project where the `vendors` directory was pushed to GitHub. We're trying to remove that `vendors` directory from the repository to make its creation a part of the build process.

```json
{
    "name": "root/my-portal",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "project",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/AppKernel.php",
            "app/AppCache.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        },
        "files": [
            "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php"
        ]
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.1",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.6",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "psr/simple-cache": "^1.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.5",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.4",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.2",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.4.0",
        "symfony/symfony": "^4.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^4.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "symfony-scripts": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": null
    }
}
```

But on a "clean" install of this project, i.e. removing the `vendors` directory and the `composer.lock` file before running `composer install` or `composer update`, everything seems to work, except for the Sensio part:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 43 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing ocramius/package-versions (1.4.2): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing psr/container (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/cache (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/contracts (v1.1.10): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php80 (v1.18.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php73 (v1.18.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.18.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.18.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v9.99.99): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php70 (v1.18.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer (v1.18.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.18.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-icu (v1.18.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/symfony (v4.4.14): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.18.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing psr/log (1.1.3): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing psr/link (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing twig/twig (v3.0.5): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing doctrine/lexer (1.2.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing doctrine/annotations (1.10.4): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing doctrine/reflection (1.2.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing doctrine/event-manager (1.1.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing doctrine/collections (1.6.7): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing doctrine/cache (1.10.2): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing doctrine/persistence (2.0.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-apcu (v1.18.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing psr/simple-cache (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/sql-formatter (1.1.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing doctrine/dbal (2.10.4): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing doctrine/doctrine-bundle (2.1.2): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.3.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing doctrine/inflector (1.4.3): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing doctrine/common (3.0.2): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing doctrine/orm (v2.7.3): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing incenteev/composer-parameter-handler (v2.1.4): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing sensio/framework-extra-bundle (v5.6.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing monolog/monolog (1.25.5): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/monolog-bundle (v3.5.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-iconv (v1.18.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing egulias/email-validator (2.1.22): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.2.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/swiftmailer-bundle (v3.5.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing symfony/phpunit-bridge (v4.4.14): Downloading (100%)
symfony/contracts suggests installing symfony/cache-implementation
symfony/contracts suggests installing symfony/event-dispatcher-implementation
symfony/contracts suggests installing symfony/http-client-implementation
symfony/contracts suggests installing symfony/service-implementation
symfony/contracts suggests installing symfony/translation-implementation
symfony/contracts suggests installing psr/event-dispatcher (When using the EventDispatcher contracts)
symfony/polyfill-mbstring suggests installing ext-mbstring (For best performance)
paragonie/random_compat suggests installing ext-libsodium (Provides a modern crypto API that can be used to generate random bytes.)
symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer suggests installing ext-intl (For best performance)
symfony/polyfill-intl-idn suggests installing ext-intl (For best performance)
symfony/polyfill-intl-icu suggests installing ext-intl (For best performance)
doctrine/cache suggests installing alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter (Required to use legacy MongoDB driver)
monolog/monolog suggests installing graylog2/gelf-php (Allow sending log messages to a GrayLog2 server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing sentry/sentry (Allow sending log messages to a Sentry server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing doctrine/couchdb (Allow sending log messages to a CouchDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ruflin/elastica (Allow sending log messages to an Elastic Search server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-amqplib/php-amqplib (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server using php-amqplib)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-amqp (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server (1.0+ required))
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-mongo (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing mongodb/mongodb (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server via PHP Driver)
monolog/monolog suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Allow sending log messages to AWS services like DynamoDB)
monolog/monolog suggests installing rollbar/rollbar (Allow sending log messages to Rollbar)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-console/php-console (Allow sending log messages to Google Chrome)
egulias/email-validator suggests installing ext-intl (PHP Internationalization Libraries are required to use the SpoofChecking validation)
swiftmailer/swiftmailer suggests installing ext-intl (Needed to support internationalized email addresses)
swiftmailer/swiftmailer suggests installing true/punycode (Needed to support internationalized email addresses, if ext-intl is not installed)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
27 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
ocramius/package-versions:  Generating version class...
ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
> Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters
Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
Class Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler is not autoloadable, can not call symfony-scripts script
Class Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler is not autoloadable, can not call symfony-scripts script
Class Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler is not autoloadable, can not call symfony-scripts script
Class Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler is not autoloadable, can not call symfony-scripts script
Class Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler is not autoloadable, can not call symfony-scripts script
```

And we can't find what could be wrong here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I copied your `composer.json` to my local environment and ran `composer update` and had the same results. The problem is, that the class `Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler` does not exist with your config. So I executed `composer require sensio/distribution-bundle`, but then I got a version conflict:

```
[...]
- sensio/distribution-bundle v5.0.0 requires symfony/process ~2.3|~3.0
[...]
- don't install symfony/process v3.4.9|don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.14
- Installation request for symfony/symfony (locked at v4.4.14, required as ^4.4) -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v4.4.14].
```

The [SensioDistrubutionBundle](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioDistributionBundle) has been archived:

> WARNING: This bundle does not support Symfony 4. Symfony Flex is a total replacement for this bundle.

I guess your best option is to check the Symfony Flex docs about what's necessary to upgrade to Flex OR rely on an older Symfony Framework version in order to use the `SensioDistrubutionBundle`.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this, @chris-döhring I'll try and upgrade to Flex as mentioned. The odd thing is the Symfony version set as 4.4.x on the composer JSON file - I guess someone wrote the version there and that was it, never bothering to try and run composer update afterwards.

Comment: Having the same problem now. @LeandroBarbosa did you manage to workaround this? Or solve maybe?